# Update manager shows x86 virtualization solution -kernel modules for DKMS

Tags: update-manager

After I upgraded from ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04. I see the "x86 virtualization solution -kernel modules for DKMS" update available in update manager. But it doesn't let me select or install it.

My virtual-box is already the latest and works without any issues.

How do I get rid of this update  ?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update manager has got it's knickers in a twist for some reason (I think it's due to the way it handles disabling and sorting out the new virtualbox sources...)

I fixed this by opening a terminal and re-installing dkms, i.e. at the prompt type:

**`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms`**

et voila, problem solved. Hope this helps