# Why are some updates not installable?

Tags: 12.04, update-manager, evolution

Whenever Update Manager runs, I am always left with these three options:

[image: update manager]

They are obviously all related to Evolution, which does appear to still be installed, but I have never used it. This has happened ever since I upgraded to 11.10 (I am now on 12.04)

Why do these items appear and how can I remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are some library files that were somehow not uninstalled while evolution was 
removed or replaced.
Ok here's what you need to do.

1. install synaptic package manager from software center.
2. Search for the evolution files showing up in the update
   manager(evolution-common, evolution-indicator.
3. uninstall those files.
4. run `sudo apt-get update` in terminal

---

Problem solved ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a while back, re-installing the package fixed the issue.

here's my experience: [Update manager shows x86 virtualization solution -kernel modules for DKMS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127605/update-manager-shows-x86-virtualization-solution-kernel-modules-for-dkms)

[image: my experience]

Comment: I checked in Software Center and it didn't say Evolution was installed. I tried to install it and get an error about unmet dependencies: `evolution: Depends: evolution-common (= 3.2.3-0ubuntu6) but 3.2.3-0ubuntu6 is to be installed`

Answer (score 0):

Your upgraded system may be unstable, so secure all data etc before proceeding.  You can try some or all of the following:

- `sudo apt-get clean`
- `sudo apt-get autoremove`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get upgrade`
- `sudo apt-get -f install`

If you get error messages, please ask.

Comment: what does all the commands do? please explain for clarification.

Comment: suggest you look at the apt-get manual.  Do man apt-get

Comment: if you can't explain what each command does, how do you know they will help?

Comment: a bunch of random apt-get commandos can anybody post...

Comment: Please look at the manual - it is not appropriate to paste all the details here.

Comment: of course not, why would you need to know what the commands does to use them. it's just safer for the user.